# How to include JPanel from other class to the main

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have this Other class, and I have made panel inside it. How I can add this panel in Main class(When I run like this I get blank window).

```
public class Other extends JFrame {

    JTextField input = new JTextField(4);

    public JPanel panel () {
        //JPanel for all
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        //Input panel
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(null);
        inputPanel.setLocation(50,50);
        inputPanel.setSize(250, 30);
        totalGUI.add(inputPanel);

        input.setSize(100,30);
        input.setLocation(150,30);
        inputPanel.add(input);

        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    public Other () {
        super("Guess The Number");
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Other obj = new Other();
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(300,300);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. don't to use main class for this purpose, 2.  create everything in constructor (Other), 3. use local variable for JFrame instead of extends JFrame

Comment: @mKorbel Why shouldn't the OP extend `JFrame`?

Comment: @msrd0 lets imagine that we have most complex GUI, how do you want to change JFrames.whatever() from another class, yes there are methods in SwingUtilities or Window[] returns arrays of ..., but then you have to create an temporary variable for JFrame, if you want or not, isn't easier to create an local variable

Comment: @msrd0 search for inheritance v.s. composition :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I just looked at the example in [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_an_Stelle_von_Vererbung#Beispiel), and I see some interfaces and one abstract class that'll need to be extended for use. Nothing prevents me from extending `JFrame` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't access the panel from the `Main` class at all, there is no need for it. To add your panel to the whole frame, write this into the `Other` constructor:

```
setContentPane(panel());
```

If you want to keep the panel and just add the panel, write this instead:

```
getContentPane().add(panel());
```

You could also use this line, but it is still there from AWT and should not be used in a Swing application:

```
add(panel());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `JPanel` to your `JFrame` on its constructor:

```
public Other(){
    super("Guess The Number");
    add(panel());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should call the add function of JFrame object and add the JPanel to it.
In your main function, do this after initialization of Other object:

```
obj.add(obj.panel());
```

Comment: Why do you do this in the `Main` class?

Comment: I saw that, and I'm using your and @Nicolas Albert way :D